# How to include a " character in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to create the following string in Python:

```
str1 = "abc"def"
```

But it gives the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-4-72818b9defc9>", line 1
  str1 = "abc"def"
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I use " in a string in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the **'** signs around the string.
Example code:

```
str1 = 'abc"def'
```